# Cómo hacer que la capa superpuesta a una imagen al hacer mouseover sea clickable

Tags: html, css, hover

Estoy aplicando un código para que al hacer mouseover sobre distintas imágenes aparezca un texto acompañado de una capa que oscurece un poco la imagen. La capa cubre por completo la imagen, que debe redirigir a otro sitio, pero al pasar sobre ella con el cursor no es clickable. Os copio aquí el código que estoy usando. ¿Alguien sabe cómo hacer para que la capa sea clickable y redirija a otro lugar? Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Os copio aquí el link donde está el código que estoy usando (Image as a img tag and a layer with text on hover over it – base settings):
http://css-workshop.com/hover-box-text-over-images-on-hover-and-more/

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) para que esa capa no tenga eventos, por ejemplo

```css
.capa {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Saludos.